# MVC Razor check radio input to enable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to have this input radio button checked base on the model but I am getting string error. Is this the correct way to set the checked enable?

Error
    'string' does not contain a definition for 'Regimens'
[image]

debugger

[image]

View

```
    <label for="RegimenReferencesC_@Model">
        <input type="radio" id="RegimenReferencesC_@Model" checked="@(Model.Regimens == (int)RegimenReferences.D ? "true" : "false")"  name="RegimenReferences" value="@((int)RegimenReferences.C)" class="regimen-reference">
        (c) @RegimenReferences.C.ToDescriptionString()
    </label>
Tried it this way too
    <label for="RegimenReferencesD_@Model">
        <input type="radio" id="RegimenReferencesD_@Model" name="RegimenReferences" checked="@(Model.Regimens == (int)RegimenReferences.D ? true : false)" value="@((int)RegimenReferences.D)" class="regimen-reference">
        (d) @RegimenReferences.D.ToDescriptionString()
    </label>
```

Model

```
public class ReferencesModel
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Regimens { get; set; }
    public Guid? GuidelineId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In your cshtml file there is a line that starts with @model . Can you post that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems clear from `<label for="RegimenReferencesC_@Model">` that `@Model` in the Razor view is a string, or that line would not work.

Therefore, when you try `@(Model.Regimens ...`, you get the error, since a string does not have a property or method named Regimens.

In other words, check your Model in the view. It is probably a string and not the object you are looking for.

Comment: from the debugger I see the model

Comment: If you see the model in the debugger, then this line should fail:

```<label for="RegimenReferencesC_@Model">``` since Model is not a string.

Answer (score 1):

You  are missing some relevant code in your post so I am going to fill in the blanks with assumptions:

Given the following Class and Enum:

```
public class ReferencesModel
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Regimens { get; set; }
    public Guid? GuidelineId { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}

public enum RegimenReferences
{
    [Description("This is A")]
    A = 0,
    [Description("This is B")]
    B = 1,
    [Description("This is C")]
    C = 2,
    [Description("This is D")]
    D = 3
}
```

and the following Helper method for displaying enum annotation text:

```
    public static string ToDescriptionString<T>(this T e) where T : IConvertible
    {
        if (e is Enum)
        {
            Type type = e.GetType();
            Array values = System.Enum.GetValues(type);

            foreach (int val in values)
            {
                if (val == e.ToInt32(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                {
                    var memInfo = type.GetMember(type.GetEnumName(val));
                    var descriptionAttribute = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute;

                    if (descriptionAttribute != null)
                    {
                        return descriptionAttribute.Description;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Your Razor code would be as follows to use a radio button and base checked on the value:

```
<label for="RegimenReferencesD_@Model">
<input type="radio" id="RegimenReferencesC_@Model" @if (Model.Regimens == (int)RegimenReferences.D) { Html.Raw("checked"); } name="RegimenReferences" value="@((int)RegimenReferences.D)" class="regimen-reference">
(D) @RegimenReferences.D.ToDescriptionString()
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks @travis-acton but I am still getting the same error about 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Regimens'

Comment: Can you tell us the exact line that is throwing?

Comment: What is on line 6?

Comment: if I use this 8 == (int)RegimenReferences.D it works.